# loop through array to find matches and return every possible solution

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small input field where this code gets activated everytime a key is pressed inside it. But it now only prints "found something" when the name exacly matches what you type in the input field.

How can change a part that when I type something like "b" it already removes the matches where there is no "b" in the name is and print every possible matches that still have a "b".

My small code to find the match.

Info is my json big array where I can loop through all the names with info[i].name

```
var textInput = $findperson.find('input').val();
    console.log(textInput);

    for (i = 1; i < info.length; i++) {
        if (textInput === info[i].name) {
            console.log('found something');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is `info` an array of results or one result?

Comment: oh sorry info is my big json blob with the info[i].name I only loop through all the names of that blob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set Flag if found any match and print them, otherwise print `found nothing`,
for `gi` `g` mean search globally and `i` mean ignore case sothat `A` will match `a` and vise verse.

```
var textInput = $findperson.find('input').val();
console.log(textInput);
found = false 
for (i = 1; i < info.length; i++) {
    if (info[i].name.match(new RegExp(textInput,"gi")) ) {
        console.log(info[i].name);
        found = true
    }
}
if(!found){
   console.log("found nothing")
}
```

Comment: Works exacly how I want! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just use `indexOf` to search for one String within another:

```
if(info[i].name.indexOf(textInput) != -1) {
```

`indexOf` will return `-1` if String isn't found within the other.

You can try searching for some letters in one of the results `'balloon', 'ball', 'apple'` in the example below:

```js
var results = ['balloon', 'ball', 'apple'];

function filterResults() {
    var input = document.getElementById('input').value;
    var resultsFiltered = results.filter(function(a) {
        return a.indexOf(input) != -1;
    });
    var result = ''; resultsFiltered.map(function(a) {
        result += a + '<br/>';
    }); document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
}
```

```html
<input id='input' onkeyup='filterResults();'/>
<div id='result'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use regex like this:

```
var textInput = $findperson.find('input').val();
var regex = new Regexp(".*("+textInput+").*","i"); 
var filtered = info.filter(function (current) {
        return current.name.match(regex);
    });
console.log(filtered);
```